# Need to get time 1 hour ago with 0 minutes and seconds in in RFC-3339 format

Tags: java, datetime

I need to get time 1 hour ago with 0 minutes and seconds in RFC-3339 format
so

```
2020-11-09T16:05:30-05:00
```

would be

```
2020-11-09T16:00:00-05:00
```

Comment: Do you already have some ZonedDateTime object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ZonedDateTime, you will need to reset the minutes and seconds, then use the formatter:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime newTime = zonedDateTime.withMinute(0)
         .withSecond(0)
         .withNano(0);

System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").format(newTime)); // RFC 3339
```

Output:

```
2021-04-27T09:00:00+03:00
```

Comment: Not quite correct. This code will leave any fractional second that may be present. Better to truncate than fill in parts.

Comment: The input string is for an `OffsetDateTime`, not a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I have added withNano(0) and retrieved the new instance. Thanks for your comments guys

Comment: It works now for the current time. I still find it simpler and hence preferrable (1) to use `truncatedTo()` and (2) to use a built-in formatter.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```java
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2020-11-09T16:05:30-05:00" )
.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS )
.toString()
```

## ISO 8601

By the way, RFC 3339 is really just a self-declared “profile” of the ISO 8601 standard. RFC 3339 makes some poor decisions where it departs from ISO 8601, so I suggest sticking with ISO 8601.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse your input as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

Your input complies with the standard ISO 8601 formats used by default in *java.time* for parsing date-time strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2020-11-09T16:05:30-05:00" ) ;
```

## Truncate

Clear the smaller parts by [truncating](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#truncatedTo(java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)) to a larger part. Truncating to hours will lop off any minutes, seconds, and fractional second (nanoseconds), leaving zero values in their place.

```
OffsetDateTime truncated = odt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;  // Zero-out minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

### One hour ago in a specific time zone

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Panama");
    String oneHourAgoInRfc3339 = ZonedDateTime.now(zone)     // Now in Panama
            .minusHours(1)                                   // 1 hour ago
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS)                   // Without minutes, seconds
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME); // RFC-3339
    System.out.println(oneHourAgoInRfc3339);
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

> 2021-04-26T21:00:00-05:00

If you want the offset for your own time zone, set `zone` to `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Basil Bourque is basically correct that for your output with an offset, -05:00, and no time zone like America/Lima, you just need an `OffsetDateTime`. So why am I using `ZonedDateTime`? This is just to take the corner case of a summer time transition (DST transition) into account. By subtracting one hour from a `ZonedDateTime` I get the offset that was valid in the specified time zone 1 hour ago, not the offset that is valid now.

`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` produces ISO 8601 format (hence ISO in the name). RFC-3339 is a simplified ISO 8601. In our case the two agree: the output you get with the formatter does fall within RFC-3339 too, so is fine for your purpose.